# Do all reducing sugars show mutarotation?

Tags: carbohydrates

Do all reducing sugars show mutarotation?

I studied that for a sugar to be reducing it must possess a free aldehydo or keto group. Also, for a mutarotation interconversion between α- and β-forms of compound are required.

If there is a free aldehydo group or keto group in the compound *must* it show mutarotation?

Note: I am a high school student so please try to explain in a simpler manner.

Comment: https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2017/08/17/mutarotation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compounds having hemiacetal in their structure give mutarotation.

Generally, all monosaccharides (glucose, fructose, ribose, arabinose, …) and disaccharides (lactose, maltose, …) give mutarotation, except sucrose.

Sucrose, despite being a disaccharide, fails to give mutarotation because it doesn't contain hemiacetal.